# Transpose or Pivot without using PIVOT or UNPIVOT SQL Editor in Metabase

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table, transpose, metabase

I am trying to transpose my table columns and rows however transpose is not yet included in the functionality of Metabase. Now I am trying to manually do it in its SQL Editor however PIVOT is not a known functionality for some reason.

I have a table with columns Interval, Count, Percentage

| Interval | Count | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 - 60 | 50 | .78 |
| 61 - 120 | 10 | .16 |
| 120 > | 4 | .06 |

And I am trying to convert it like this

| 0 - 60 | 61 - 120 | 120 > |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 10 | 4 |
| .78 | .16 | .06 |

What I have tried is using as a trial.

```
select 
    max(case when Interval = '0 - 60' then Count end) as "0 - 60"
    max(case when Interval = '0 - 60' then Count end) as "0 - 60"
    max(case when Interval = '0 - 60' then Count end) as "0 - 60"
from t
union
select 
    max(case when Interval = '0 - 60' then Percentage end) as "0 - 60"
    max(case when Interval = '0 - 60' then Percentage end) as "0 - 60"
    max(case when Interval = '0 - 60' then Percentage end) as "0 - 60"
from t
```

But the resulting query will always put percentage at the top first even if I change the order of select

| 0 - 60 | 61 - 120 | 120 > |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .78 | .16 | .06 |
| 50 | 10 | 4 |

Comment: I added order by "0 - 60" desc as a countermeasure however there will be possibilities of 0 - 60 count being 0 and 0 percentage so it might be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following Code

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    max(CASE WHEN Interval = '0 - 60' THEN Percentage END) AS ' 0 - 60',
    max(CASE WHEN Interval = '61 - 120' THEN Percentage END) AS ' 61 - 120',
    max(CASE WHEN Interval = '120 >' THEN Percentage END) AS ' 120 >',
    2 as sort_order
  FROM #TESTS

  UNION 

  SELECT
    max(CASE WHEN Interval = '0 - 60' THEN Count END) AS ' 0 - 60',
    max(CASE WHEN Interval = '61 - 120' THEN Count END) AS ' 61 - 120',
    max(CASE WHEN Interval = '120 >' THEN Count END) AS ' 120 >',
    1 as sort_order
  FROM #TESTS
) t
ORDER BY sort_order ;
```

Good Luck;

Comment: Is there a way to "Dynamically" do this? Since the interval is already known but what if the intervals are different how do I still transpose this?